# How to select only last entries based on a especific column value keeping the current table order

Tags: mysql, sql, select, distinct

I have a table that keeps track of the last changes applied to students in a student catalog. I want to return the data from this table every minute so I can sincronize only the necessary entries with my java app.

It happens that I only need the last event_type entry per ID. I've just created a small art to graphically explain what I want but the site doesnt let me post it because of my reputation being to low yet. I'll try to post its link though:

```
What I have                                        What I would like
+---------------------+------------+------------+  +---------------------+------------+------------+
| event_time          | event_type | student_id |  | event_time          | event_type | student_id |
+---------------------+------------+------------+  +---------------------+------------+------------+
| 2015-08-16 11:42:08 |          1 |         37 |  | 2015-08-16 11:44:30 |          1 |         37 |
| 2015-08-16 11:42:29 |          1 |         37 |  | 2015-08-16 11:45:47 |          2 |         37 |
| 2015-08-16 11:43:51 |          2 |         37 |  | 2015-08-16 12:21:40 |          1 |         44 |
| 2015-08-16 11:44:13 |          3 |         37 |  | 2015-08-16 12:21:49 |          3 |         44 |
| 2015-08-16 11:44:30 |          1 |         37 |  | 2015-08-16 12:21:55 |          2 |         30 |
| 2015-08-16 11:45:47 |          2 |         37 |  | 2015-08-16 12:22:00 |          3 |         37 |
| 2015-08-16 12:21:28 |          2 |         44 |  | 2015-08-16 12:27:08 |          2 |         44 |
| 2015-08-16 12:21:40 |          1 |         44 |  +---------------------+------------+------------+
| 2015-08-16 12:21:49 |          3 |         44 |
| 2015-08-16 12:21:55 |          2 |         30 |
| 2015-08-16 12:22:00 |          3 |         37 |
| 2015-08-16 12:27:08 |          2 |         44 |
+---------------------+------------+------------+
```

Any idea how do I do that? I searched the site but couldnt find anything suitable for this. Thanks for the help!

Comment: So you want the 3 most recent events for each student?

Comment: how do you arbitrarily come up with that jpg ? so much for last one per

Comment: if my Answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32030445/1816093) is of use, tailor it up. That Answer was something like the last response to tickets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

E.g.:

```
SELECT x.* 
  FROM my_table x 
  JOIN my_table y  
    ON y.student_id = x.student_id 
   AND y.event_time >= x.event_time 
 GROUP 
    BY x.student_id
     , x.event_time 
HAVING COUNT(*) <= 3 
 ORDER 
    BY event_time;
```

or, faster...

```
SELECT event_time
     , event_type
     , student_id 
  FROM 
     ( SELECT x.*
            , CASE WHEN @prev = student_id THEN @i := @i + 1 ELSE @i := 1 END i
            , @prev := student_id 
         FROM my_table x
            , (SELECT @i:=1,@prev:='') vars 
        ORDER 
           BY student_id
            , event_time DESC
     ) n 
 WHERE i <= 3
 ORDER 
    BY event_time;
```

Comment: Oh my... beautiful answer. Exactly what I was looking for. I have a lot to learn in terms of SQL statements haha. Thanks pal!

Comment: @AdrianoVieira You should accept the answer if you are satisfied with it :)

Comment: Nice. First time around here, sorry! =D. Answer accepted. The faster way is awesome. =D

Answer (score 0):

```
select max(time), type, id
from your table
group by type, id
```

should work. If I understood you, you need latest entry for every (type, id) pair, which this query will retrieve.